# I don't understand the grammar of this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I don't understand the grammar of the following sentence. (The part in **bold**)

> Note that it doesn't matter how the hello method becomes attached to the object in this form. Remember that we previously defined hello as a standalone function. **Let's see what happens if we attach is to the object dynamically**:
>
> Source: https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/, Member Functions section.

What I thought should be correct is this version:

> Let's see what happens if we attach the object dynamically.

So could anyone clarify why my version is incorrect and/or why that version is correct?

Comment: It's clearly a typo of "Let's see what happens if we attach _it_ to the object dynamically"

Comment: @Kreiri: :O sounds reasonable, I thought that was a special grammar about _is to Verb_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Kreiri is correct in their comment. This is a typo, and the correct sentence should be

> Let's see what happens if we attach **it** to the object dynamically:

Comment: Thank you for helping me confirm the information.